# Background Worker in external reference (DLL) locking main thread

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I use background worker almost daily and works great.  Today I came to an instance though where I needed to put my background worker in a separate project then the one I was running because I needed to use this class in two different projects in my solution.  When I tested the coding on a winforms form, it works perfectly, handling my coding on the background thread.  When I try to reference this class from an external project, all of my coding seems to run just fine, but it does not appear to be doing anything on a background thread as it should be, causing my main window to lockup.

Is there any way around this / what is the best practice for ASYNC calls in an external class.

Note I basically created a class that u call start, and an event fires when data is ready, so it's not like my external project is waiting for the method to complete.

Thanks in advance

---

Example of my senerio

Solution ABC has two projects.  Project A and Project B.  Project A is my WPF application and B is my DLL doing the work.  Inside project A I have

```
Dim SmartCardData as new Solution.B()
SmartCardData.Start()

Project B has a sub

Public Sub Start()

   worker.workerConnect.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub workerConnect_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles workerConnect.DoWork

'loop 10 seconds connecting to my device
e.Result = true

End Sub

Private Sub workerConnect_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles workerConnect.RunWorkerCompleted

  RaiseEvent Scanner_Connected()

End Sub
```

(Sorry I can't get it to show my coding as code, not plain text)

Comment: Is your external project Forms or console based?  Also, you can view the threads and call stacks in the debugger, this will help you understand the external app's runtime behavior.

Comment: The external project is a COM object, and that is definitely what is locking up my coding.  I am looking for a solution to call a method on a COM object that does not lock me up now, with little luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the debugger first.  Set a breakpoint on the DoWork event handler.  When it breaks, use Debug + Windows + Threads and verify that it runs on a worker thread and that you see the Main Thread listed.  Double-click the main thread and look at the call stack, ensure it is idle and is not doing something like waiting for the BGW to complete.  That's a guaranteed deadlock.

The next failure mode is one that's hard to diagnose.  You can freeze the UI thread, even with a background worker, when you call ReportProgress too often.  The UI thread is flooded with invoke requests and doesn't get around to doing its normal duties anymore.  Like painting and responding to input.  Everything still works like it should, the worker and the UI thread are actually running, you just can't see it.

This happens easily, reporting progress more than about a thousand times per second is the danger zone.  It depends on how much work the UI thread needs to do in the ProgressChanged event handler.  The best way to diagnose if that's your problem is to add System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(45) after the ReportProgress() call.  This usually slows down the worker enough to give the UI thread a chance to catch up.

You solve it by reporting progress at a rate that's useful to human eyes.  Which at 25 updates per second doesn't see anything but a blur anymore.  Collect bgw results in a collection object like List<> so you can update the UI with a single call, something like AddRange().  This might still not be good enough if the BGW just generates results far faster than the UI can ever consume, you'll have to skip results or slow down the worker artificially.

Comment: When I did that my main thread is on ID 8312 at and by breakpoint is on 6707 "Worker Thread" with location "DoWork".  Main thread just says its on VerifyAPIReadOnly().   

As for progresschanged, i do not do anything for that because I really do not care to send any progress.  I simply call the function in an external DLL, that function starts a bg worker.  bgworker_dowork does about 10 seconds of work (calls another external DLL that interacts with a card reader). Once dowork is done, it passes the data i need to complete, which raises an event passing it to main thread.

Comment: You main thread should be idle, on Application.Run() inside the .NET message loop code.  Press F5, tap your foot, Debug + Break All and check again.  Your program deadlocks if it doesn't go idle.  Post the stack trace in your question if you can't decode it.

Comment: That is what it was idle on but i replaced my coding with a massive loop and it worked fine, so it has to do with my call to my card reader. I am going to debug this more, but will mark yours as answered since it helped the most.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The background worker handles it completed code in the main thread stoppping the UI from responding. Don't use the background worker if you wan't the UI to update while the backgroundworker is finishing.

Comment: That is pretty hard to make out. The whole point of a backgroundworker to my understanding is so it executes on a new thread and your UI does not lock up. It has always worked like that for me.  It opens a thread, does what I need with the args I pass it, then returns the args I pass back when complete.

Comment: What is hard to make out? When the background worker finishes it executes the BackgroundworkerCompleted event on the main UI thread block all other main UI thread actions untill Application.DoEvents is called.

Comment: My BackgroundworkerCompleted only fires after all my coding is completed that is locking up. Were talking fractions of a second to send the data.  The problem is that the coding inside DoWork is locking up my main thread in the main project... which should never happen because the DoWork is supposed to be on a thread separate from the main thread.

Comment: You might need to add some code to let us see what is going wrong. Threads don't just block other threads for no reason unless shared resources are edited from multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If your external app is consoled based, use the ThreadPool instead to run your async work.  The BackgroundWorker delegate needs a message pump in order to execute on the main thread.

Comment: Main project is a WPF application and sub project is a class dll